# Prove that the series doesn't converge on any point of the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^n, \,z\in \mathbb{C}$ doesn't converge on any point of the unit circle.

Edit:
$|z|=1$. $\left\vert\sum_{k=0}^{n} kz^k \right\vert \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}k|z|^k=\sum_{k=0}^n k$-diverges.

How can I make the first inequality an equality?

Comment: 1. You haven't defined $\varepsilon$ so it is difficult to answer... in the definition of limits of sequences (series are sequences) , $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$, not the other way around. 2. A power series always converge at its center. The origin is not a point of the unit circle. 3. Only the boundary $|z|=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series cannot converge unless the general term tends to $0.$ Here $|nz^{n}| \to \infty$ for $|z|=1$.